# How to protest a down vote?

Tags: support

I'm new here, and one of my posts got **down voted**.

How to I protest that?

Can the down vote get cancelled?

Comment: lol, I've got downvoted for this too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take to meta (as you did) and try to explain why you thought it was downvoted "incorrectly". However, downvotes are subjective and stackexchange relies on a model of community self-moderation. There is no formal way to protest a (single) downvote.
You may also investigate the edit history to see if downvotes happened before any major revisions to understand potential downvotes.